# Javascript syntax error in python robotframework

Tags: javascript, python, robotframework

I'm using robot framework and selenium2 libraries. When I try to set text in a text field using Javascript, I get the following error:

```
'WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'
```

Below is my function

```
def jsSetTextByName(self, name, vValue):
    "Setting value using java script with name"
    print "document.getElementsByName('" + name + "').value='" + vValue + "'"
    self.execute_javascript("document.getElementsByName('" + name + "')[0].value=('" + vValue + "')")
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your variables are? What is your HTML? Looks like a pretty self explanatory error to me: `syntax error`?

Comment: I think you need to remove `()` after `value`. Im not sure.

Comment: name holds xpath and vValue holds value to enter in text field (interger)

Comment: The first step in debugging this is to create a variable that contains the javascript to be executed so that you can print it out or log it so that you can see exactly what javascript will get.

Comment: is it possible that either `xpath` or `vValue` contains a single quote? Also, why does `name` contain an xpath if you're using `getElementsByName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with my python version and chrome driver. I have updated everything and all looks good now. Thank